# Regression? Visual Studio 2010 Unpinned Pane Will Not Hide With Escape Key If Mouse is Positioned Over the Pane

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Maybe I'm a keyboard shortcut nut, but I like using CTRL-ALT-F to get my last search results.  The window will slide up and I can quickly move to the next result.  Or I can hit ESC and go back to what I was doing.  That last bit is the rub.  If the mouse cursor happens to be positioned over the pane when it slides up, it won't disappear with the ESC key.  This was not the case in VS 2008.  I wonder if some option in VS 2010 is causing the behavior???

Comment: Doubtful, probably has more to do with the complete rewrite in VS2010.  Use connect.microsoft.com for feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Hans-Passant, I've submitted this as a bug at connect.microsoft.com:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/699294/visual-studio-2010-unpinned-pane-will-not-hide-with-escape-key-if-mouse-is-positioned-over-the-pane#details